# Scale Image, then save to DB (Blob)

Tags: java, image, jdbc, imgscalr

I have just started using the [imgScalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) Image Scaling library.

I can get the code to scale the images (I'm pretty sure this works).

```
BufferedImage fullImage = Scalr.resize((BufferedImage) ImageIO.read(imageStream), fullImageSize);
BufferedImage thumbImage = Scalr.resize(fullImage, thumbImageSize);
```

---

**Backstory**
This is used in a tomcat6 webapp. I pass the image onto a servlet, and read it into an InputStream called "imageStream".

Before resizing/scaling the image, what I was doing was taking that InputStream and saving it to the DB (Oracle11+) **`Blob`** field using a `PreparedStatement`, like so:

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
st.setBlob(1, imageStream);
```

This was working fine as I could save it no problem and retrieve it with no problems.

---

**The Issue**
The issue is now that I'm scaling the image(s) they are being converted to a `BufferedImage` which I can't save directly to the DB using my `PreparedStatement`.

Instead, what I'm trying to do is convert the `BufferedImage` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` which then gets read into an `InputStream`, see code below:

```
BufferedImage fullImage = Scalr.resize((BufferedImage) ImageIO.read(imageStream), fullImageSize);
BufferedImage thumbImage = Scalr.resize(fullImage, thumbImageSize);

ByteArrayOutputStream fullImageArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream thumbImageArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ImageIO.write(fullImage, imageMimeType, fullImageArray);
ImageIO.write(thumbImage, imageMimeType, thumbImageArray);

InputStream fullImageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fullImageArray.toByteArray());
InputStream thumbImageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(thumbImageArray.toByteArray());

// DB INITIALISATION STUFF

PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
st.setBlob(1, fullImageStream);
st.setBlob(2, thumbImageStream);
```

---

**Error Details**
When I execute the statement, I get a `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into`. Which I know that it clearly means that I'm trying to insert a `NULL` value into the column, so that's not the issue.

The problem is that at some point during my conversions or scaling, the image value gets lost and I end up with a `null`

---

**The Question**
The question comes in two parts:

1. **What am I doing wrong?**
2. **Is there are better way to scale an Image in java and save it to a DB (Blob) field?**

Comment: try calling `fullImageArray.close()` and `thumbImageArray.close()` after the line `ImageIO.write(thumbImage, imageMim....)`. My guess: the output stream wasnt flushed and therefore the input stream has no data. You should check what `fullImageArray.toByteArray().length` is and same for the thumb image.

Comment: @ug_ Did the '.close()' on both, but no difference (both Arrays are length 0, before and after the 'close').

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I'm on jre7.

Comment: have you checked that the image is being re-sized correctly? For instance check that the width and height are > 0. Or possibly setup a little application that uses the Scalr library to take an image from a file, re-size it and save it.

Comment: @ug_ Yes, both images are being resized correctly... fullImage: Width = 450 Height = 450, thumbImage: Width = 150 Height = 150. It is as you pointed out the part where the `BufferedImage` gets written into the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. For some reason the data gets lost.

Comment: [Fixed it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27612803/1377865)! Thanks @ug_ for pointing me in the right direction! **Still happy for suggestions to a better way of doing this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by the commonly known problem of [Pebcak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error), or in this case "developer error"!

For future reference, what I did wrong was that I had used the incorrect image type for the `ImageIO.read` method:

**Problematic:**
`ImageIO.write(fullImage, imageMimeType, fullImageArray);`

"`imageMimeType`" was the full mime type, so in this case it was "image/jpg". This is incorrect as the value should have been simply "jpg" which is what the [`ImageIO.write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream)) method was expecting.

**Fixed:**
`ImageIO.write(fullImage, imageMimeType.replace("image/", ""), fullImageArray);`

I know that the `replace` is safe in this case as the string will always follow that pattern.

Comment: Nice job solving it and thanks for coming back to answer your own question. That may help future readers of the problem to solve their own problem which is what the sites about. Make sure to accept your answer once available (I think theres a delay before you can do so)!